# soapclient returns failed to load external entity

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I try to consume a simple webservice using PHP unfortunately I get the following error messages wich (as it seems to me) say that the SOAP URL can not be opened, but in the Browser it does work fine (http://www.webservicex.net/uklocation.asmx?WSDL).

Any Idea where is my mistake?

The Errormessages:

> Warning:
>   SoapClient::SoapClient(http://www.webservicex.net/uklocation.asmx?WSDL)
>   [soapclient.soapclient]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
>   in /home/sia-deutschland_de/www/tests/test.php on line 14
>
> Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: I/O warning
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "http://www.webservicex.net/uklocation.asmx?WSDL" in
>   /home/sia-deutschland_de/www/tests/test.php on line 14 Exception
>   Error!
>
> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://www.webservicex.net/uklocation.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load
>   external entity "http://www.webservicex.net/uklocation.asmx?WSDL"

And my code:

```
<?php
// include the SOAP classes
require_once('nusoap.php');

try { 
            $options = array( 
                'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2, 
                'exceptions'=>true, 
                'trace'=>1, 
                'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE 
            ); 
            $client = new SoapClient("http://www.webservicex.net/uklocation.asmx?WSDL", $options); 
    // Note where 'Get' and 'request' tags are in the XML 


//$client = new soapclient("http://www.webservicex.net/uklocation.asmx?WSDL", $options);

$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
// Display the error
echo 'client construction error: ' . $err ;
} else {
$answer = $client->call(’GetUKLocationByCounty’,
array(
'Country'=>'London'));

$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
// Display the error
echo 'Call error: ' . $err;
print_r($client->response);
print_r($client->getDebug());
} else {
print_r($answer);
}
}



} catch (Exception $e) { 
    echo "<h2>Exception Error!</h2>"; 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't really a mistake the solution is quite simple: I installed the code on a shared hosting package and it seems from there internet access is not allowed. From my local system it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also, like in my case the problem can be on the url, I had a space on beginning of my variable that contains the url and that caused the error.